# Send request to Airvisual API with Postman

Tags: request, postman

I am using react and use axios for making request to the airvisual API. However when I made the request in localhost it returned with a 404 status (I registered to Airvisual and got the key). I read Airvisual documentation and it mentioned using postman to make the request so I download postman and tried it out and the request is now success. I do not understand why it does not succeed in the first place and if I have to use postman for that API call, how do I connect it with my localhost.
Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get(
                'api.airvisual.com/v2/countries?key=c441738e-dbc0-4f06-babc-bb126a29c19f'
            )
            .then((response) => console.log(response));
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Edit your question with your code rather than adding a comment

Comment: I just editted now